# Electrostatic potential resolving singularity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, singularities, greens-functions

I'm trying to determine the electrostatic potential caused by a specified charge density function:
$$
\rho_c(\vec{r}) =\begin{cases}
1 & \vec{r} \in V\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The solution using Green's function is then:
$$
\phi(\vec{r}) = \iiint_{V} \frac{\rho_c(\vec{r}')}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\|} d \vec{r}'
$$

I can understand how this integral can be easily evaluated so long as $\vec{r} \not\in V$ since there is no singularity in the integral, however I don't know how to resolve the integral if $\vec{r} \in V$, since this appears to cause the integral to become infinite/undefined.

Suppose for a concrete example that $V$ is an axis-aligned rectangular prism with opposing corners at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. How do I find $\phi(\vec{r})$ inside of this box, and how do I generalize that procedure to any arbitrary $V$?

Comment: The singularity is integrable...

Comment: I'd imagine it is since I can see one alternative solution to be to use the Green's function method to produce boundary conditions outside of $V$ for a Poisson PDE solver, however I don't know what mathematical tools I need to use to evaluate this integral "directly". Suppose I took the 1D case with $\rho_c(x) = 1$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$. I think this produces the integral $\phi(0) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 |x|} dx$, which doesn't converge, but using the "Poisson with BC's" approach gives $\phi(0) = \frac{6 \pi + \log(3)}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}$.

Comment: In 1D there is no Green function, but in 2D there is and it is proportional to  $\ln \sqrt{x^2+ y^2}$ which is locally integrable as well in $dxdy$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example: what is the improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$? It is $\frac{1}{2}$ even though $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\to \infty$ as $t\to 0^+$. The reason is that although the function is unbounded, it is not "bad enough" for the purposes off integration. This is what @Valter Moretti means by "the singularity is integrable". It goes off to $\infty$ slowly enough that it can be integrated over to yield a finite result. On the other hand, $\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}=\infty$.

So, for integration purposes, mere unboundedness of the function alone is not enough to deduce anything about the finiteness of the integral. In $3$ dimensions,
\begin{align}
\int_{\|\mathbf{r}'\|\leq 1}\frac{dV'}{\|\mathbf{r}'\|}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{r'}4\pi r'^2\,dr'=4\pi\int_0^1r'\,dr'
\end{align}
is certainly finite. And in general, in $\Bbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align}
\int_{\|\xi\|\leq 1}\frac{1}{\|\xi\|^p}\,d^n\xi&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{r^p}A_{n-1}r^{n-1}\,dr=A_{n-1}\int_0^1\frac{dr}{r^{p+1-n}}
\end{align}
so this is finite if and only if $p+1-n<1$, if and only if $p<n$ (here $A_{n-1}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\Bbb{R}^n$).

Comment: hmm, so the 1D case is still unbounded? Or am I miss-understanding the second criteria since I can still directly solve the 1D Poisson's equation for $\rho_c = 1$ for $x \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: @helloworld922 in the 1-D case it is not integrable as I mentioned: $\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}=\infty$. In 3-dimensions there's no issues. I even gave the condition in $n$-dimensions for when such inverse-powers of distance yield finite integrals. (though for $1D$ solving Poisson's equation is trivial, you just integrate $u''(x)=\rho(x)$ twice (I'm ignoring the various constants))

Comment: I suppose a follow-up question is why can I solve Poisson's equation "directly" by applying appropriate BC's at $x=\pm 2$ and find $\phi(0)$?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: $\iint \frac{d^2 \phi(x)}{dx^2} dx dx = \phi(x)$, $\iint h(1-x) h(1+x) dx dx = \frac{1}{2} (2 c_0 x + (x - 1)^2 h(x-1) - (x+1)^2 h(x+1))+c_1$, then I just need to apply appropriate boundary conditions to find the constants of integration?

Comment: oh, hmm, if I use different boundary conditions from evaluating the Green's function at different points I get completely different constants. I suppose that means finding a consistent set of constants $c_0$ and $c_1$ doesn't exist and this approach doesn't work?